# SOLID где создавать экземпляр класса

Tags: php, solid, абстрактная-фабрика

Исходя из SOLID принципов, внутри какого-то класса нельзя создавать конструкцию `new SomeClass;` во избежании жестких и неочевидных зависимостей.
Прав ли я, если нет, то в каких случаях можно так делать, чтобы не противоречить SOLID?
Если прав, то где же тогда, черт его дери создавать нужные мне объекты, если мы все зависимости прокидываем через аргументы конструктора, но сам-то класс должен создаваться где-то?

Comment: SOLID - это свод рекомендаций, а не жестких правил.